# "sparsifying" a binary (over the field F2) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory, sparse-matrices

Assume I have a matrix $A \in GF(2)$, i.e., $A_{i,j} \in \{0, 1\}$ and the sum is modulo 2. Is there any known algorithms/methods to sparsify (reduce the number of non-zero entries) $A$ while keeping its row space the same? A simple way, for example, will be to add every two rows and if the resulting sum is of lower weight than one of the two rows we replace them. 
Is there any known good/better method?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this what row reduction, aka Gaussian elimination, is for?

Comment: It won't necessarily result in a sparse matrix. For example the matrix A = [[1 0 1 1], [0 0 1]] is in reduced form, but the matrix B = [[1 0 1 0],[0 0 1]] spans the same space and is more sparse

Comment: I think we got cut off. But is there a guarantee that there is a way to sparsify every matrix?

Comment: That's a good question.  I haven't found anything concrete online. Playing a bit with some examples it seems like in most cases there is a sparse matrix

Comment: Your example, three comments up, I don't get – a matrix with four entries in the first row, and three in the second row?

Comment: sorry, A = [[1 0 1 1], [0 0 0 1]] and B = [[1 0 1 0],[0 0 0 1]]

Comment: But $A$ isn't in reduced row-echelon form.

Comment: why not? a matrix is in row echelon form if
all nonzero rows (rows with at least one nonzero element) are above any rows of all zeroes (all zero rows, if any, belong at the bottom of the matrix), and
the leading coefficient (the first nonzero number from the left, also called the pivot) of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it. Am I missing something? every [] is a row in $A$

Comment: That's row echelon form. *Reduced* row echelon form has one more requirement; the pivot is the only nonzero entry in its column.

Comment: Ok, it is still easy to find counter examples: A = [[1 0 1 1], [0 1 1 1]] B = [[1 1 0 0] ,[0 1 1 1]]

Comment: This is equivalent to finding a minimum basis of a matroid. Hence you could indeed use a greedy algorithm, like you describe, and I'd expect you cannot do much better.

Comment: We're not far from discussing error-correcting codes here. E.g., the generating matrix for the simplest Hamming code, $$\pmatrix{1&0&0&1&1&0&1\cr0&1&0&1&0&1&1\cr0&0&1&0&1&1&1\cr}$$ All the nonzero vectors in the row space have weight $4$, so no further sparsification can occur.